# CSS - Hexagonal background image

Tags: html, css, background

I need to use an image of a hollow hexagon as a background for some content in my site. It kind of should look like this:

[image]

But I'm having all kinds of trouble laying out the content inside the hexagon.

So far I have this:

```
.hex-bg {
    background-image: url('/images/diamond.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

What would you guys think it's the best way to approach this scenario?

Comment: It's always asking for trouble to try to align an image with content. If a user increases text size, for example, the whole thing breaks. And various devices handle things differently.  So the first thing I'd do is consider how you want to handle *flexibility*. For example, would you consent to that hexagon shape expanding vertically when the content grows?

Comment: yes, @ralph.m is right. How do you want to handle expanded height? or is height fixed? Please tell us more

Comment: Height could be fixed if no other option exists. Obviously, I would prefer the hexagon to adapt to the content's height if possible

Answer (score 0):

### [JSbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/jaxujicula/edit?html,css,output)

```
.hex-bg {
    background-image: url('/images/diamond.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    min-height: 30px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    width:250px;
    height:290px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-size:14px;
}

.hex-bg img{
    max-width:50px;
    padding:20px;
}

.text-wrapper{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

As long as the text is not too long and doesn't spill out ofthe bottom of the hexagon it should work. In the case you need an exact wrap of the text you might want to consider another approach such as [CSS Text Wrap](http://www.csstextwrap.com/)